# ubuntu 18.04/firefox freeze

Tags: firefox, video

I am learning Blender. While switching between Blender and the instruction video on Firefox, the video freezes and Ubuntu seems to partially freeze. I can open apps but not use them and the keyboard does not work. After closing and reopening Firefox the video works but the keyboard doesn't. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*P.S.: Since I don't have enough reputation to comment, writing as answer*

Did you check if its because your Firefox & Blender together are occupying all your RAM ? One way could be to open **System Monitor** and in it check:

- **Processes** tab and sort by **Memory** column
- **Resources** tab and check in **Memory and Swap History** section, the % of RAM used